# How to join outer query table alias name into inside sub query using oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I have small query and I am asking you after much googling. please let me know the solution.

Here my query is, I have joined two tables and make it the result as a table with alias name and that table (result) can i use it to join with another table inside the subquery ?

```
select *
from (select t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col3 
      from tbl1 t1 join
           tbl2 t2
           on t1.col1 = t2.col1
     ) cte1
where round(sysdate - cte1.col3) * 24 > (120 +
        (select count(distinct holidat_date)
         from holiday_tbl join 
              cte1.location = hm.location
         where hm.location = 'ABC'
        ) * 24
     )
```

When i try to use common table variable c1 inside the sub query i am getting the error. If the query is not possible let me know the solution please...

Here my functionality is hours between the current date and `cte1.col3` (it is a date), is there any holidays if yes how many?

Comment: Here c1 is cte1

Comment: Do you really have a column named `"ABC"`? Double quotes are for identifiers (e.g. column names). If you want to compare the column `location` with the string `ABC` you have to use **single** quotes in SQL:  `hm.location='ABC'`

Comment: By the way, `cte1` is an inline view, not a common table expression. A CTE is a subquery defined in a `WITH` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your query as below

```
select * from
(select t1.col1,t1.col2,t2.col3 from tbl1 t1 join tbl2 t2 on t1.col1=t2.col1) cte1
where round(sysdate-cte1.col3)*24>(120+(
select count(distinct holidat_date) from holiday_tbl hm where cte1.location=hm.location
and hm.location="ABC")*24)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `cte1` is not returning anything called `location`.  So, that is necessary.

Second, `hm` is not defined.

Third, the syntax isn't quite right in the subquery in the `where`:

```
select *
from (select t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col3, ?.location
      from tbl1 t1 join
           tbl2 t2
           on t1.col1 = t2.col1
     ) cte1
where round(sysdate - cte1.col3) * 24 >
      (120 +
        (select count(distinct holidat_date)
         from holiday_tbl hm join 
         where hm.location = cte1.location and
               hm.location = 'ABC'
        ) * 24
       )
```